¿Como formatear un JSON con Resource en Laravel 11?
soy nuevo por aquí, quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar con el siguiente problema, he agotado ya horas tratando de buscar información y no se en realidad si lo que quiero se puede hacer o no ó haya otra forma.
Estoy desarrollando una Api en laravel 11 en lo cual he ido avanzando constantemente, en este punto me encuentro realizando una consulta a base de datos para q me devuelva cuantas tablas tiene, algo sencillo.
Schema::connection($this->connection)->getTables()

la respuesta de este código es un JSON como el siguiente
[
  {
    "name": "tabla1",
    "schema": null,
    "size": 16384,
    "comment": "",
    "collation": "latin1_swedish_ci",
    "engine": "InnoDB"
  },
  {
    "name": "tabla2",
    "schema": null,
    "size": 49152,
    "comment": "",
    "collation": "latin1_swedish_ci",
    "engine": "InnoDB"
  }, 
]

ahora lo que quisiera hacer es poder formatear ese Json para quitar o anexar datos, por lo general en otros ejercicios lo he echo creando un Resource, pero por lo que entiendo me funciona porque esta anclado creo a algún modelo de datos ya que las consultas realizadas son directas a alguna tabla, pero en este caso por lo q veo como no es una tabla entonces no me funciona, la respuesta q me da es que no existe el campo x que intento acceder desde el Resource.
Bien espero no haber hecho muy extenso el tema y haberme dato a entender, gracias de antemano

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

despues de seguir buscando me di cuenta que me estaba complicando, no se si esto es una solucion formal, pero cubre las necesidades del momento, si alguien logra algo diferente bienvenido sea.
Pude solucionar tomando el Json que me daba la consulta
Schema::connection($this->connection)->getTables()

lo recorro y crear uno nuevo con los datos y campos ajustados a mi necesidad, dejo por aqui el ejercicio simple por si es de ayuda para alguien mas
$columns = Schema::connection($this->connection)->getColumns($request->table);
    $columns = [];
    foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
        array_push($columns, [
            'name' => $column['name'],
            'collation' =>  $column['collation'],
            'engine' => $column['engine'],
        ]);
    }

aqui solo quite los campos q no me interesa :D

Si querias convertir ese json a array podias usar la función json_decode()

Los Resource los puedes usar sin modelo asociado ya que aceptan cualquier cosa como entrada. Esto es un ejemplo de como se haria usando Resources
La ruta (sin controlador):

Route::get('/tables', function () {

    $data = json_decode('[
        {
          "name": "tabla1",
          "schema": null,
          "size": 16384,
          "comment": "",
          "collation": "latin1_swedish_ci",
          "engine": "InnoDB"
        },
        {
          "name": "tabla2",
          "schema": null,
          "size": 49152,
          "comment": "",
          "collation": "latin1_swedish_ci",
          "engine": "InnoDB"
        }
      ]');

    return TableResource::collection($data);
});

El resource:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class TableResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}

Hay mas info en español en https://documentacionlaravel.com
